# Unit test data that includes HTML: What format(s) can include mix of utf8 & HTML ? XML, JSON or other?

Tags: xml, unit-testing

I have unit test code that needs to iterate through blocks of HTML and confirm that the parser code works correctly.

Currently we store the test cases in XML. But we are challenged by having to create CDATA tags by hand on the html segment.

Should I be using json or some other format instead?

Our data is utf8 and includes a lot of non-Latin letters. We create these test cases by hand, hand creating the xml in VSCode. Our current workflow is to open an existing test case and save it under a new name, pasting in the relevant new data.

Please advise.

Examples:

**XML below** is an example test file.

**XSD for our XML** is below. The "RawPayload" element is a raw response from an HTTP GET and includes HTML and other stuff (headers) in it (currently we put the whole element inside CDATA tags). The "ParsedOutput" element is a multi line block of text with a number of different alphabets in it. It is non-tagged text, and currently is NOT in a CDATA block.

**Example XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestCase>
  <TestSuiteVersion>1</TestSuiteVersion>
  <TestName>SampleTest-2</TestName>
  <TestEnabled>true</TestEnabled>
  <TestURL>https://www.testserver.com/ict/1256-l/</TestURL>
  <RawPayload><![CDATA[
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="he"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">sh({
      ... snip ...</div></div></body></html>
    ]]></RawPayload>
  <ParsedOutput>to avenge( את)

    לִנְקֹם ~ לנקום
    
    </ParsedOutput>
  <TestSuiteVersion>1</TestSuiteVersion>
</TestCase>
```

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="TestCase">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="TestSuiteVersion" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" />
             <xs:element name="TestName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
             <xs:element name="TestEnabled" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" />
             <xs:element name="TestURL" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="1" />
             <xs:element name="RawPayload" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
             <xs:element name="ParsedOutput" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="1" />
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I already suggested you what to do via XSLT. Please edit your question, and add (1) input XML sample, and (2) desired output XML.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky  Thank you very much. I enhanced the OP to engage your questions. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does it help that JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation?

Comment: @Rob Ummmmm, no? I am not claiming to be able to "see through the problem."  I have a challenge, and welcome any and all input into how to successfully engage the challenge. Thank you in advance for suggestions!

Comment: Please join the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240293/room-for-yitzhak-khabinsky-and-jonesome-reinstate-monica